# Replace every second instance of word in each line of the file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace every second instance word of each line with `sed`.

**For example:** If I had a line as below

```
i_ref_clk i_ref_clk i_ait_rstn i_ait_rstn abc kiran/def
```

should be replaced as below.

```
i_ref_clk kiran/i_ref_clk i_ait_rstn kiran/i_ait_rstn abc def kiran/def
```

Only second instance of word is replaced with `kiran/`.

**My attempt :**

```
echo " i_ref_clk i_ref_clk i_ait_rstn i_ait_rstn abc def def" | sed 's/ / kiran\//2'
```

**Output:**

```
i_ref_clk kiran/i_ref_clk i_ait_rstn i_ait_rstn abc def def
```

---

**My Question:**

Please help me with the proper `sed` or any Linux command which does the above job.

Comment: If you want to append "kiran/" to the occurrence, what is "subinst"?

Comment: @WilliamPursell sorry for the typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, if you are ok with `awk`.

```
awk -v var="kiran/" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(++a[$i]==2){$i=var $i}};delete a} 1' Input_file
```

Or adding a non-one liner form of above solution:

```
awk -v var="kiran/" '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(++a[$i]==2){
      $i=var $i
    }
  }
  delete a
}
1
'   Input_file
```

Output for shown sample will be as follows.

```
i_ref_clk kiran/i_ref_clk i_ait_rstn kiran/i_ait_rstn abc kiran/def
```

Comment: I think you want `if(++a[$i] == 2)` to get only the 2nd instance.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, Sure William I have edited it now, thanks for letting me know. I thought OP is looking for more than 1 count, thanks and cheers.

Comment: Although one has to wonder if we should also replace the 4th, 6th, 8th, etc. instances :)

Comment: That won't produce the posted expected output from the posted sample input. It'll be missing `def` as the 2nd-last output word. That may be a mistake in the question though, idk.

Comment: @EdMorton, Hi Ed sir, greetings. Yes that looks like a typo to me but OP only could confirm that

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU sed`

```
$ line='i_ref_clk i_ref_clk i_ait_rstn i_ait_rstn abc def def'
$ echo "$line" | sed -E 's|\b(\w+)\b(.*)\b\1\b|\1\2kiran/\1|g'
i_ref_clk kiran/i_ref_clk i_ait_rstn kiran/i_ait_rstn abc def kiran/def
```

- `\b(\w+)\b` capture a whole word (`\b` are word boundaries and `\w` matches any word character)
- `(.*)` any number of characters
- `\b\1\b` match same whole word as matched by first capture group
- `\1\2kiran/\1` in replacement section, add text as required
- note that `|` is used as delimiter assuming it wouldn't conflict with input characters and assumes that a word is repeated only twice